# Missing Param in Rails 6 Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first Rails 6 project. Stuck on this. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have a form on index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @volunteer_submission do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

with a controller

```
 def create
    @volunteer_submission = VolunteerSubmission.new(volunteer_submission_params)
    @volunteer_submission.save
    redirect_to @volunteer_submissions
  end

  def volunteer_submission_params
    params.require(:volunteer_submission).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

I get this

```
Started POST "/volunteer_submissions" for ::1 at 2020-03-29 13:55:38 -0700
Processing by VolunteerSubmissionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"OIlkqKqXJeA7XjYPqQHubZFGm64ivCe+9fimFwO8uBrtXJ3iPyiIZbgWtWS4FXFnS+KhZYCT5CgzN76YCTqC+Q==", "email"=>"a", "first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a", "commit"=>"Save "}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 666)
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: volunteer_submission):

app/controllers/volunteer_submissions_controller.rb:16:in `volunteer_submission_params'
app/controllers/volunteer_submissions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

If I leave out the volunteer_submission_params..it will attempt it...but I think rolls back because I have the DB set up for it not to accept null values. So...I'm not sure why the params aren't passing.

```
Started POST "/volunteer_submissions" for ::1 at 2020-03-29 13:40:33 -0700
Processing by VolunteerSubmissionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"1cpAIcVZuM/qcJdt1KNg2rYMIX58yDVCO5mRMXmbiUjMHr81cAseqJZN/TDYDFaGXGLPJhs7iIwhvQgr5g/RRg==", "email"=>"a", "first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a", "commit"=>"Save "}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/volunteer_submissions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
  VolunteerSubmission Create (7.1ms)  INSERT INTO "volunteer_submissions" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2020-03-29 20:40:33.125665"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-29 20:40:33.125665"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/volunteer_submissions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/volunteer_submissions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 7.8ms | Allocations: 3296)
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :volunteer_submissions

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  get 'volunteers', to: 'volunteer_submissions#index'

  root to: 'pages#home'

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is the fact that you are sending your params without a `volunteer_submission` key.

Based on this method

```
  def volunteer_submission_params
    params.require(:volunteer_submission).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

Your controller is expecting `{ "authenticity_token"=>"OIlkqKqXJeA7XjYPqQHubZFGm64ivCe+9fimFwO8uBrtXJ3iPyiIZbgWtWS4FXFnS+KhZYCT5CgzN76YCTqC+Q==", "volunteer_submission" => { "email"=>"a", "first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a" }}`.

Comment: Make sense. How do I send that key?

Comment: Solved it by using scope to send the volunteer_submission. <%= form_with scope: :volunteer_submission, local: true  do |form| %>

Comment: FWIW if you're using param wrapper (which I think is enabled by default in rails), it should automatically wrap your keys inside the volunteer_submission key.

Answer (score 0):

the form should look like this `<%= form_with(model: item, local: true) do |form| %>` also in `model: item` you should put the name of your model rb file located in `app/models`
in my case its `app/models/item.rb`
so my form is `<%= form_with(model: item, local: true) do |form| %>`

Comment: Added 'local: true'...and it's still saying the parameters are missing. And if I understand you...yes, my model is app/models/volunteer_submission.rb so @volunteer_submission.

Answer (score 0):

for me I had this issue because I was using an html input inside the rails form and was passing in the name of value without the model name.

```
<% form_with model: order_item do |f| %>
  <input type="number" name="weight_in_oz"></input>
<% end %>
```

params look like this

```
  {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "weight_in_oz"=>"16", "commit"=>"Add To Cart", "controller"=>"order_items", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

I fixed this by adding the model name before the input name and put the attribute in an array which nests the attribute inside of a model hash inside of params.

```
  <% form_with model: order_item do |f| %>
      <input type="number" name="order_item[weight_in_oz]"></input>
    <% end %>
```

and this is the params after just what I was expecting

```
   {"authenticity_token"=>"....", "order_items"=>{":weight_in_oz"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Add To Cart", "controller"=>"order_items", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```